# Create "browsable" source code based on ctags output?

Tags: ctags

Is there a way to take a program's source code, run ctags on it and generate an HTML file for each of original source code file, with hyperlinks at places where ctags can see relations in the code? How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe http://lxr.sourceforge.net/en/index.php is what you're looking for.